# set folder permission in metro app using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing metro app using Windows 8 release preview and C#(VS 2012), I'm stuck with creating file Asynchronously. I'm using following code to create file in folder

```
StorageFolder storageFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Data");            
StorageFile File= await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(File, result);
```

Where "Data" is foldername,"result" is text and "DataFile" is filename, But I got `UnAuthorisedAccessException` at this line

```
 StorageFile File= await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("DataFile",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I understand that my folder "Data" is read only, but how do I change the folder attribute to writable, I also tried `storageFolder.Attributes` property but it is readonly property.

Comment: Why can't you create the DataFile inside your application's storage? Why does it need to be created in the data directory of your package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get write access in the InstalledLocation. It would basically be like writing to "Program Files" (it actually is a folder inside of "Program Files"), which as far as I remember was blocked as far back as Vista for security reasons.

You should try writing to ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder instead.